# Using a termset as Refiner without Search Result Web part

Tags: search, term-store, refiner, term-set

I am working on a SharePoint on-premise environment, and following is the scenrio I want to achieve;

I want to add a refinement web part to a page (without Search Result Web Part) which contains one refiner. The refiner is a TermSet conaining several terms. I have added a Managed Metadata Field to the Pages Library which points to the termset. So when you navigate to the page (containing refinement web part) it will show all pages and you can filter the pages using the refinement web part.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to show these pages that are filtered somehow. Did you have an ordinary list view in mind? If yes, then (provided this is SP2013 we are talking about) you would have to develop a custom web part (it can be just script/content editor web part with html/javascript) which would get the possible refiner values (directly from TermSet or via search query) and clicking on a refiner value can add a filter to the view via query string parameters. If that is what you are looking for, I can update my answer with some examples to get you started.

But you can also create a search-like experience with having that Managed Metadata Field as a refiner and displaying the pages as search results. Why do you want to skip the Search Results web part?